# Sort on calculated field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to add two field value then apply sorting on nodejs MONGODB....Guys please help..i am new in this

```
userModel.find({ $query: {}, $orderby: { 'total':{$add: [ '$field1', '$field2' ]}}: -1  },function(err,data){
   if(err)
       throw err;
   else {
       response.json({testing: data});
       console.log(data);
    }
})
```

I have to add field 1 and field 2 value first after that sorting occurs..
I have tried many thing but still stuck..
can any one please help me out..

Comment: See [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) just like you are actually shown in the documentation of [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/reference/operator/aggregation/add/)

Comment: @NeilLunn i tried to use aggregate too..but that was not working properly may be i coded wrong query..i am  not able to get proper solution..

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You cannot just say "I tried that" since we do not know what you actually "tried" unless you showed us, which you chose not to do in your question. Anyhow you have been now linked to relevant examples of doing the same thing that you are asking, so you should be able to follow what those are doing.

Comment: Actually i have to sort document based on result of two fields addition..but aggregate is sorting via two fields...

Comment: There are **two** very obvious links in the big colored box above your question. Please actually read them as they explain **in detail** how to solve your problem. This is how it is done. The links to existing answers are the answer to your question.